Do "two digits are consecutive" make a PIN easier to guess?
My workplace recently started to insist that we install some MS software on our phones, seemingly to improve security (whether or not it does isn't relevant). One thing it insists on is that the PIN used to unlock the iPhone doesn't have any consecutive digits, giving as its reason that that would make the PIN "easy to guess". My PIN, which it disliked and insisted I change, was something like 757128 (not actually that, of course).
I changed it to 135791, and it was perfectly happy. That seems to me to be weird.
Am I missing something here?
